# Considered most unbearable = considered very unbearable?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage, superlatives

In this sentence, does **most** mean **very**, or is it a shorter version of **the most**? Are both meanings possible here?

> Well, the diseases that human beings focus on are the ones considered
>      **most** unbearable.

Comment: To give you an answer for something tagged with 'meaning-in-context', the context of the passage is helpful, as opposed to just a sentence all on its lonesome.

Comment: My bad. I meant to ask what meanings are **possible** within the context of this sentence. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "most" can stand in for "the most" *and* "very" but it could also be thought of to mean "extremely", however to me your excerpt reads:

> well, the diseases that human beings focus on are the ones that are considered *the worst* to bear.